# Containerized applications and hardware resources

Tags: virtualization, docker, gpu, hardware-virtualization

Linux user here. With increasing frequency, I am considering using containerized applications for several applications, mainly to avoid dependency problems and stressful reinstallations in a hurry.

In most cases, these applications (which I run natively nowadays) require extensive use of my GPU.

I wonder if the containerized applications can also make full use of the GPU power (this, without having to deep-dive into advanced configuration files/procedures), or if the containerization creates a minimum usable environment and stays like that.

Is there a default behavior for containerized applications in this sense? Can the application make full use of the CPU and GPU?

Comment: I believe the default is max usage (competing with the host) unless you set limited reservations. For example, Docker has configurations for managing nvidia GPU resources per container: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/ using the [nvidia container toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-toolkit)